# How to open a file from a list in PowerBi when click on a row/column

Tags: powerbi

I have search for a while and can't find a solution to this problem.

If i press the 00002 here i want it to open the invoice file from a folder. Is this possible in PowerBI.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not a local file, but if you have a web server that can serve the file you can [Add hyperlinks (URLs) to a table or matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-hyperlinks-in-tables).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to bad it don't support serverfile/localfile

Comment: @Jonas local file would be based of a relative path, only useful if your powerbi is apart of a repo/solution. Agree with webserver, if i remember correctly, blob storage have end points you can point it towards that too?